# Retrieving Data from Database

Tags: java, jdbc

I want to retreive some column name and values from database. Condition is something as follows:

I have a column 'name' and some others columns as who's name starts with 'a' like aRaj,aHari.

```
name   aRaj  aHari

italy   5      6
rome    8      9
```

I want to retrieve this data with values in a form like this:

If column is aRaj then

```
aRaj_italy 5
aRaj_rome  8
aHari_italy 6
aHari_rome 9
.
;
and so on
```

I was trying to do it something like this but not getting a proper way to do it

```
for(int i=1;i<rsMetadata.getColumnCOunt;i++){
rsMetadata.getCoumnName.starts(a)
//my code to write it to a file
}
```

Please give me suggestions as to how I can do this?

Comment: What error (or result) do you get? At least, `getColumnCOunt` should be changed to `getColumnCount` to compile.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to get the desired output:-

```
ResultSetMetaData rsmd=rs.getMetaData();  
int c=rsmd.getColumnCount();
for(int i=2;i<=c;i++)
{
    if(rsmd.getColumnName(i).startsWith("a"))
    {
        while (rs.next()) 
        {
            System.out.println(rsmd.getColumnName(i)+"_"+rs.getString(1)+" "+rs.getInt(i));

        } 
        rs.beforeFirst();
    }
}
```